# How create a vector with pre-set values of sine on matlab to use on C# fixed point? To apply on DFT algorithm

Tags: c#, matlab

I want to create a DFT program in C# fixed point, but without calculating sin and cossine values inside the program. Instead, I want to generate them on matlab, and just store them inside a vector to get acessed by the code.

The part of the code where it happens is:

```
for(i=0;i<256;i++){
for(j=0;j<512;j++){

sin(2*pi*i*j/512)
```

Notice that they are too many values, and some of them would be the same sometimes, example: 2*10, 10*2, 5*94, 94*5, etc.

I thought about using advantage of the periodicity of the sine function, to generate less number.
What I need help with:

**How could I, instead of using `sin(2*pi*i*j/512)`, use only values of a vector in the same order they had on matlab, inside that loop, taking advantage of the periodicity of that trigonometric function?**

Comment: Generate `v = sin(2*pi*(0:511)/512);` in Matlab and then use `v(mod(i*j,512))` in your C# program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate

```
v = sin(2*pi*(0:511)/512);
```

in Matlab, and then use

```
v(mod(i*j,512))
```

in your C# program.